# Rails ActiveRecord not converting time to UTC but saving unconverted time as UTC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, timezone

I am using Rails 2.3.3 with Postgresql.

In my application environment.rb file I have set `config.time_zone = 'UTC'` and in my before_filter I set `Time.zone = current_user.time_zone`.

The problem I face is the Time that gets saved is in the users time_zone but gets saved as UTC in the database.

For example if I select  12:00 am IST (i.e +530 IST) it gets stored as 12:00 am UTC. However locally the configurations seem to work as expected and while fetching the data the time gets converted to the users time_zone so it gains 530 hours.

Would appreciate some help on this.

Thanks

Comment: So the problem is that you select a time in your form and that exact time is saved as UTC, but you expect it to be saved with the IST time offset?

Comment: No I expect the time to be converted to UTC and then saved. Here the time gets saved without getting converted to UTC time.

Comment: what do you mean by it works locally? Works on your development machine but not in production ?

Comment: I've had a similar issue some time ago with local and production differences concerning summer and winter time. Try resolving your errors by manually calling (for example) self.time.utc in your model before saving your record and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes works on my development machine. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 4):

Do you use time or datetime as the database column type for your object?

[This recent (and very similar) question to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745960/time-select-form-helper-interprets-new-time-object-as-utc-not-as-configured-time) could be resolved by changing the type from time to datetime.

Comment: The solution was to use Time.zone.parse(event.start_date) which i wasn't doing. I assumed that changing the Time.zone to the user timezone would automatically take care of that which I believe is wrong. Thank you